# Shell script with pipes fails to execute on Linux using java Runtime Process

Tags: java, linux, npm, sed, process

I want to parse the result of npm ls command, namely the tree of dependencies to extract the root level ones. I use Java 1.8 and Runtime Process and ProcessBulder to do that.

I run the code on two platforms: 
1. Linux xxxxxxx-ThinkPad-W541 4.15.0-55-generic #60~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 4 09:03:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. Linux xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 9 11:56:22 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)

On the Ubuntu it works without problems on RHEL Linux it fails

This is my code to do the trick

```java
String cmdStr1 = "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin; cd " + packageDir.toString() + "; npm ls --prod --depth=0  > " + this.workspaceDir.resolve("dependencies_tree.tmp") +  ";";
String cmdStr2 = "cat " + this.workspaceDir.resolve("dependencies_tree.tmp") + " | sed -e 's/^├─┬ //;s/^├── //;s/^─┬ //;s/^└─┬ //;s/^└── //;' | sed '/^[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/-].*/d' | sed -e 's/\\^//' | sed '/deduped/d' | sed -e 's/UNMET DEPENDENCY //' | sed -e 's/UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY //' | sed '1 d' | sed -e 's/\\@/:/g' -e 's/^:/\\@/' | sort | uniq ";

String[] cmd1 = { "/bin/sh", "-c", cmdStr1};
String[] cmd2 = { "/bin/sh", "-c", cmdStr2};

try {
...
  logger.debug("Running command: " + cmdStr1);
  Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
  logger.trace(output(p1.getInputStream()));
  int exitCode1 = p1.waitFor();         
  logger.debug("Result 1: " + exitCode1);

  logger.debug("Running command: " + cmdStr2);

  Process p2 = new ProcessBuilder(cmd2).redirectOutput(new File(dependenciesFileAbsolutePath)).start();

  logger.debug(output(p2.getInputStream()));
  int exitCode2 = p2.waitFor();
  logger.debug("Result 2: " + exitCode2);

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

The first command returns with exit code 1 the second with exit code 0.
For the first command - it should return like that because of UNMET DEPENDENCIES in it's result.
I can't get the second command working on RHEL

The expected result - is a list of root level dependencies from the output of npm ls in dependenciesFileAbsolutePath
Actual result an empty file.

My suspection that is something wrong with the second command but why it doesn't work on RHEL only then

Need your help!

Comment: The first command extracts the npm ls output to the dependencies_tree.tmp without problem. It is the second command that fails to put results after piping into the dependenciesListAbsolutePath. I have checked that second command runs from the bash and sh without problem and does the job on both environments. I need to have it from java

Comment: Can you run any sed command at all from java on RHEL? If not, then that's a question in itself. If so, then maybe try building up slowly to what you have here and seeing where it breaks.

Comment: Yes I can run - for example this one: npm ls --prod --depth=0 | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/ -]//g' -e 's/^[ \\t@]*//' | sed '/deduped/d' | sed -e 's/UNMET DEPENDENCY //' | sed -e 's/UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY //' | sed '1 d' | sed -e 's/@/:/g' -e 's/^:/@/' | sort | uniq;  It is not fails from Java as well as from /bin/sh

Comment: Great, so as you morph that into the version that fails you will hopefully be able to pinpoint the code that makes the difference between working and not. For example, the version that works uses `npm ls` directly instead of using `cat` on a temporary file. Does it still work if you use `cat` (keeping everything else the same)?

Comment: Hi jas! Yes this command works on RHEL through Java: String cmdStr2 = "cat " + this.workspaceDir.resolve("dependencies_tree.tmp") + " | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/ -]//g' -e 's/^[ \\t@]*//' | sed '/deduped/d' | sed -e 's/UNMET DEPENDENCY //' | sed -e 's/UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY //' | sed '1 d' | sed -e 's/@/:/g' -e 's/^:/@/' | sort | uniq";

Comment: The below one doesn't although it works when entering directly into bash or sh:
  //String cmdStr2 = "cat " + this.workspaceDir.resolve("dependencies_tree.tmp") + " | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/]//3' -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/]//2' -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/]//1' | sed -e 's/^[ \\t@]*//'| sed '/^[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/]/d' | sed '/deduped/d' | sed -e 's/\\^//' | sed -e 's/UNMET DEPENDENCY //' | sed -e 's/UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY //' | sed '1 d' | sed -e 's/@/:/g' -e 's/^:/@/' | sort | uniq";

I use the npm ls on the same project so it shouldn't affect

Comment: Finally I have found the problem myself - this expression works:   String cmdStr2 = "cat " + this.workspaceDir.resolve("dependencies_tree.tmp") + " | sed -e 's/^├─┬ //;s/^├── //;s/^─┬ //;s/^└─┬ //;s/^└── //;' -e 's/^[ \\t@]*//' | sed '/^[^a-zA-Z0-9@.\\/-].*/d' | sed -e 's/\\^//' | sed '/deduped/d' | sed -e 's/UNMET DEPENDENCY //' | sed -e 's/UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY //' | sed '1 d' | sed -e 's/@/:/g' -e 's/^:/@/' | sort | uniq "; The problem was a missing expression: 's/^[ \\t@]*//'